# all rails forms appear as though left aligned in span3 div

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and all the input fields/forms in the app look like they are in a span3 leftaligned div. How can I fix this and have default input widths?

I've used bootstrap on another rails app and never got this error. Any ideas?

E.g. The following code renders an input that is about 200px wide instead of 500.

_new_message

```
<div class="input-append" style="width: 500px " >
<%= form_for [@booking, @booking.messages.build], :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, placeholder: "Compose Message" %>
<%= f.submit "+", class: "btn inline" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

booking.html.erb

```
<div class="bookinginfo">
<div class="well booking">  
<h3>Private Msssages</h3>
<hr />
<div id="ajaxmessagesform">
    <span><%= render 'messages/new_message' %></span>
</div>
</div>
</div
```

Comment: What does the CSS class `input-append` look like? If you remove the css completely what does it look like?

Comment: The forms do not have css so there is no input-append class in my custom.css.scss. When I remove the css the problem persists.

Comment: Then your issue is outside the scope of the snippet you've provided.  You need to expand the range of code you provide.  What does the container look like?

Comment: Ive added the calling html.erb. Is it possible I'm overriding a css keyword?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Added the following css:

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: usually you would add a class to your fields